# Django - objects attributes represented by BoundField in template: I just want a string

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a Django model class like:

```
from django.db.models.deletion import PROTECT
from django.db.models import ForeignKey

class TScript(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    category = ForeignKey(TCategory, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name') # protect TScript from deletion; TScript belongs to TCategory
    service = ForeignKey(TService, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name')
    platform = ForeignKey(TPlatform, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name')
    command = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False) # now save as string to avoid problem
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=False) # the supervisor of this user, fill in the form of script
    interval = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False) # seconds
    # oid = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, default="1.3.6.1.4.1.41019.2.7.1.1.30.1")
    timeout = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False) # seconds
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    out = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    error = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    lastrundate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    insertDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    # overriding to save model with user of this session got from request, to fix 
    # '''Exception ValueError(u"save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.",)'''
#     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
#         obj.username = request.user.username
#         super(TScript, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__ on Python 3
        return " - ".join(["ID: " + str(self.id), "Category: " + str(self.category), "Service: " + str(self.service), "Platform: " + str(self.platform), 
                           "Command: " + self.command, "Machine: " + self.machine, "Username: " + str(self.username), "Supervisor: " + self.supervisor, 
                           "Interval: " + str(self.interval), "Timeout: " + str(self.timeout), "Status: " + str(self.status), 
                           "Out: " + self.out, "Error: " + self.error, "Description: " + self.description, 
                           "Last run time: " + (datetime.strftime(self.lastrundate, const.DATE_FORMAT_FULL_YMDHSS) if self.lastrundate is not None else ""),
                           "Insert date: " + (datetime.strftime(self.insertDate, const.DATE_FORMAT_FULL_YMDHSS))
                           ])
```

As you can see, it has some `ForeighKey` associate to it. It also has an attribute called `name`, another is `id`.

Now, I have this serializer:

```
class TScriptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TScript
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'service', 'platform', 
                  'command', 'machine', 'username', 'supervisor', 'interval', 'name',
                  'out', 'error', 'timeout', 'status', 'description',
                  'lastrundate', 'insertDate')
```

Now, when I send a list of `TScript` to the template, I have this function in `view.py`:

```
@login_required
def manageralarm(req):
    logger.info("MANAGERALARM Start HTML")
    ...

    allScripts = operationsDB.getScripts() # retrieve all the TScripts
    arrAllScripts = []
    for sc in allScripts:
        serSC = TScriptSerializer(sc)
        arrAllScripts.append(serSC)

    logger.info("array script list: " + repr(arrAllScripts))
    return render(req, 'manageralarm.html',{"arrAlarms":arrAlarms,"SNMP_OID_GENERAL":config.SNMP_OID_TRAP,"arrOids":arrOids, "allScripts":arrAllScripts})
```

In the template, I render them in a `<select>` combobox.

```
<select id="scriptCombo" name="scriptCombo" class="form-control" style="display: none" >
    <option value="0" selected="selected"> - SELECT A SCRIPT TO ATTACH THE ALARM - </option>
        {% for s in allScripts %}
    <option value="{{s.id}}">{{s.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

All seems fine, but I see `<BoundField>` in the combobox, instead of the `name`s of `TScript`.

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at last it turns out that the serialization is not necessary, I just need to pass the list onto the template and done. So, these lines are not needed:

```
arrAllScripts = []
    for sc in allScripts:
        serSC = TScriptSerializer(sc)
        arrAllScripts.append(serSC)
```